# Why does an instance of HttpErrorResponse not trigger the error function of a subscription to a server response in Angular using HttpClient?

Tags: angular, http, typescript, rxjs

I have an API call that sometimes gets this error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …} error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 0statusText: "Unknown Error"url: null }
```

In my code, the server call is handled like so... (Disclaimer, some code has been reduced to a simpler version for brevity sake)

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

getData() {
    const apiRoot = 'http://whatever.../getSomething...';
    const params = new HttpParams().set('foo', 'bar');
    const body = { params };
    return this.http.get(apiRoot, body)
        .map(res => res)
        .catch(err => Observable.of(err));
}
```

The server response is subscribed to like so...

```
this.getData().subscribe(
    response => {
        this.setApiResultsData(response);
        console.log(response); // <-- where the "error" is printed
    },
    error => {
        this.setApiResultsError(error.message);
        console.log(response); // <-- where I would think the error would go is never triggered... ???
    }
);
```

My question is, why does it not get passed to `error` in the subscription? Am I doing something wrong? I'd like to handle errors correctly, so I'm open to suggestions

Comment: remove `.catch(err => Observable.of(err));` from `getData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `getData` you are essentially recovering from the error by catching it and returning a new observable:

```
.catch(err => Observable.of(err));
```

Thus the calling method no longer sees an error. You could catch the error and throw a new one:

```
getData() {
    // ...

    return this.http.get(apiRoot, body)
        .map(res => res)
        .catch(err => Observable.throw(err));
}
```

Or you could remove the `catch` from inside `getData`, so the original error propagates:

```
getData() {
    // ...

    return this.http.get(apiRoot, body)
        .map(res => res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because the response has a body - in which case, Angular does not consider a `status` of zero to be an error. See the following code in [`common/http/src/xhr.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.2/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L170-L173):

```ts
// Normalize another potential bug (this one comes from CORS).
if (status === 0) {
  status = !!body ? 200 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense now. Thanks. It is a CORS issue as well, I just wasn't clear on why a status code of 0 wasn't an error.